# JQuery not replacing html

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the deal, i have the following jquery code that should add the array values to specific #id, buf it does not replace the code, only add more, and i need a little help to make it replace the html on othe link click.

Code:

```
function changeClass(curClass){
    switch(curClass){
        case "Schoolgirl":
        case "Fighter":
            var charSkillsNames = ["text1","text2","text4","text5"];
        //loop show array values
        listSkillsNames(charSkillsNames);
        break;
    }
}
function listSkillsNames(arr){
var length = arr.length,
    element = null;
    $("#skills").html(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            element = arr[i];
            $(this).append("<li>"+element+"</li>");
        }
    });
}
```

this works well but i need it to replace the html inside the "#skills" id when i click on the link that makes it work

PS: problem is really here

Comment: Could you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are keep appending new items to the element always without removing the existing items.

Just empty the `skill` element, also there is no need to use the `.html(function(){})` here

```
function listSkillsNames(arr) {
    var length = arr.length,
        element = null;
    var $skill = $("#skills").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        element = arr[i];
        $skill.append("<li>" + element + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't empty the HTML of `#skills` element. Use `$("#skills").html("")` to empty it.

```
function listSkillsNames(arr){
    var length = arr.length,
    element = null;
    var $skills = $("#skills");
    $skills.html(""); // empty the HTML
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        element = arr[i];
        $skills.append("<li>"+element+"</li>"); // append new items
    }
}
```